# Gnome App Theme on Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: xubuntu

I am using Xubuntu with a Greybird light theme. When I run any gnome app (like gthumb / epiphany-browser) it shows up with a dark title bar or window.

If I run the app from the terminal with : GTK_THEME=Adwaita gthumb, it comes up with a nice light-grey window.

I would like to make this permanent for all gnome apps. I tried to tweak the gnome settings (gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Adwaita") but no success.

Any idea?